# Can I test locally when developing for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to get started with Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk and as I learn more about it, it seems like I will not be able to test my webapp locally.  I understand I can build a war file and run it in a local Tomcat, but it looks like once I need a datastore (I want to use dynamodb) I will have to connect to aws.  Ideally I would be able to run a test instance locally (not having to connect to aws to test).  Is that a reasonable thing to do or am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally got around to sending a message to Amazon about this.  Someone got back to me quickly, telling me that I must be connected to AWS services to do this sort of development work.

Comment: Have you thought about potentially using some kind of mocking to achieve this? I was just considering the same question myself.

Comment: That certainly could work.  I don't know enough about AWS to know what that would entail though.  Ideally the app/datastore configuration would be the same or at least similar for local development and on Amazon's servers, but I don't know how that would be accomplished.  Once I found that local dev wasn't supported, I decided to go with App Engine instead.  Do you have any ideas of how such a setup would be done though?

Comment: Amazon's AWS website claims it is easy to run locally, but then omit any details on how to set this up. I can't find any details on the web and after 2 days of poking around I still can't figure it out. If you have figured out how to do it, please share! :)

Comment: What's worked for me (see my edited answer): Run/debug locally, remotely connect to services through appropriate security settings.

Answer (score 4):

The checked answer is correct - it is not possible to run AWS services locally.  I'm adding more information and references.  Just by way of comparison, Google App Engine which I also use does provide this capability and I have found it incredibly useful.

A few months ago someone named Wade on the AWS developer relations team [solicited feedback](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=370069) from the developer community on what mocks would be useful for developers for this purpose.

Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk does support [integrated debugging using the Eclipse IDE](http://d1un85p0f2qstc.cloudfront.net/eclipse/remote-debugging/index.html).  If you have a good Internet connection and squint your eyes, it almost feels like you're running locally.

But, I think there may be a solution to what the original question was really trying to do.  I do this all the time.  I connect my locally running Tomcat instance to a remote Amazon hosted datastore instance by modifying the database security appropriately.  At first I was worried about performance, but it's been really fast for me.  And you effectively get local debugging while connecting to a remote data source.